# haproxy rate-limit sessions : is there a way to send back 404s instead of making excess requests wait in the backlog queue?

Tags: haproxy

When the request rate exceeds the rate-limit value specified, the excess requests are queued up in a backlog queue, affecting those requests' latency. Is there a way to avoid this, and send the excess requests automatic 404s ? 
( I have tried reducing the backlog queue parameter to 1 , and the average latency still shoots up due to queueing under heavy load )

Answer (score 1):

yes, simply match them with the "fe_conn_rate" ACL and direct them to a serverless backend in which you use the "errorfile 503" directive to write a response of your own. However I really discourage you from sending 404. 503 is the appropriate response when you cannot serve a request due to overloading. 404 might be cached and might cause some search engines to remove the entries they have for your site.

Comment: The closest equivalent I could find to fe_conn_rate in the docs is fe_sess_rate.  I added this to the frontend for the throttle, but this setting caused frontend to be 'FULL' under heavy load.  Is there a workaround for this problem, or is this just misconfigured?